# The using of bypassSecurityTrustHtml seems to break hyperlink

Tags: angular, typescript, sanitization

I try to detect an Url or plain text in a string value. If it's an Url, the function return a HTML hyperlink using `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`. The hyperlink is displayed, but when I click on it, nothing happen. However, Chrome recognize it as a link and when I right click, I can select «Open in a new window» and it works.

Angular code:

```
public formatReservedField(value: string) {
  let pattern = /(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\//gm;

  if (pattern.test(value)) {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<a href='" + value + "' target='_blank'>" + value + "</a>");
  }

  return value;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div [innerHTML]="formatReservedField(reservedField)"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've found it!

I've set the change detection of my component to `OnPush` strategy and it works now:

```
@Component( {
    ...
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    ...
}
```

Comment: What on earth, why does this work? After using pipes all day to fix my user content... This is the key to the entire clickable hyperlink issue.

<div [innerHTML]="Value | safeHtml"></div>

Comment: why??????? who can tell me why...